# Android parsing multiple HTML tables with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse an HTML page on the internet to retrieve data from a table in it with Jsoup. But the page I want to parse contains more than one table. How can I do that? Is that possible?

Edit:
Here is the page I want to parse:

http://metudex.com/mobilepac/browse.php?SEARCH=calculus&kriter=X&Submit=Search

I want to retrieve data from the tables with book info.

Comment: It is entirely possible. Get a list of tables matching your requirements and iterate over them.

Comment: Kindly add the html you want to parse and indicate the table you want.

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes, please mark it so the topic can be considered closed. If not, please provide some feedback, or an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://metudex.com/mobilepac/browse.php?SEARCH=calculus&kriter=X&Submit=Search").get();

Elements els = doc.select("td:has(span.briefcitDetail)"); //gets every td that has a child span with class briefcitDetail

for(Element el : els) {
    System.out.println("--" + el.text());
}
```